# Appending a large amount of columns into 1 column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, append

I have a dataset of ~700 columns. I'd like to join all columns into a single column.

Input:

```
id | A   | B  | C   | D  | E  | F  | ... | Z
0  | yes | no | yes | no | yes| no | ... | no
1  | no  | no | yes | no | no | no | ... | no
2  | yes | yes| yes | yes| yes| no | ... | no
```

Output:

```
id | A   | B  | C   | D  | E  | F  | ... | Z  | joined_column
0  | yes | no | yes | no | yes| no | ... | no | yes no yes no yes no ... no
1  | no  | no | yes | no | no | no | ... | no | no no yes no no no ... no
2  | yes | yes| yes | yes| yes| no | ... | no | yes yes yes yes yes no ... no
```

I've used the following in the past. However, I'm looking for a way to scale this when you're working with a large amount of columns.

```
def join(df):
list = []
    for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        list.append( str(df['A'][i]) + ' ' + str(df['B'][i]) + ' ' + str(df['C'][i]))
    return list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the dataframe `df`

```
   id    A    B  ...    Y    Z                                      joined_column
0   0  yes   no  ...  yes   no  yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes ...
1   1   no   no  ...   no   no  no no yes no no no no no no no no no no no no ...
2   2  yes  yes  ...  yes  yes  yes yes yes yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes yes...
```

One can use a custom lambda function inside [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) as follows

```
df['joined_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)

[Out]:

   id    A    B  ...    Y    Z                                      joined_column
0   0  yes   no  ...  yes   no  0 yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no ye...
1   1   no   no  ...   no   no  1 no no yes no no no no no no no no no no no n...
2   2  yes  yes  ...  yes  yes  2 yes yes yes yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes y...
```

However, as one doesn't want the `id` to appear in the `joined_column`, one can add `x.drop('id')` as

```
df['joined_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.drop('id').astype(str)), axis=1)

[Out]:

   id    A    B  ...    Y    Z                                      joined_column
0   0  yes   no  ...  yes   no  yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes ...
1   1   no   no  ...   no   no  no no yes no no no no no no no no no no no no ...
2   2  yes  yes  ...  yes  yes  yes yes yes yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes yes...
```

Alternatively, for this last case, one can also leverage Numpy, more specifically [`numpy.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) as follows

```
df['joined_column'] = np.array([' '.join(x.astype(str)) for x in df.drop('id', axis=1).values])

[Out]:

   id    A    B  ...    Y    Z                                      joined_column
0   0  yes   no  ...  yes   no  yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes no yes ...
1   1   no   no  ...   no   no  no no yes no no no no no no no no no no no no ...
2   2  yes  yes  ...  yes  yes  yes yes yes yes yes no yes yes yes yes yes yes...
```

Answer (score 3):

Given `df`:

```
     A    B    C    D    E   F
0  yes   no  yes   no  yes  no
1   no   no  yes   no   no  no
2  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  no
```

Doing:

```
cols = df.columns

# As a string:
df['joined_column_str'] = df[cols].agg(' '.join, axis=1)

# As a list:
df['joined_column_list'] = df[cols].agg(list, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E   F       joined_column_str             joined_column_list
0  yes   no  yes   no  yes  no    yes no yes no yes no    [yes, no, yes, no, yes, no]
1   no   no  yes   no   no  no      no no yes no no no      [no, no, yes, no, no, no]
2  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  no  yes yes yes yes yes no  [yes, yes, yes, yes, yes, no]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `agg` to aggregate data over a specific axis using a specific operation:

```
df['joined_column'] = df.agg(' '.join, axis=1)
```

Potentially use

```
df['joined'] = df.iloc[:,1:].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
```

if you don't want to join the first (or any other column).

I used `' '.join` to join the values with a space as separator.

`axis` is set to `1` because you want to join columns and not rows.

Comment: Your phrasing of wanting to join columns and not rows is confusing. We set`axis` to `1`/`columns` to "Apply function to each row".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a list comprehension:

```
df['joined_column'] = [' '.join(item) for item in df.iloc[:,1:].values]

   id    A    B    C    D    E   F   Z              joined_column
0   0  yes   no  yes   no  yes  no  no    yes no yes no yes no no
1   1   no   no  yes   no   no  no  no      no no yes no no no no
2   2  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  no  no  yes yes yes yes yes no no
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
df['joined_column'] = df.iloc[:,1:].add(' ').sum(axis=1).str.rstrip()
```

---

Yet another possible solution, using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

df['joined_column'] = reduce(lambda x,y: x+' '+y, [df[i] for i in df.columns[1:]])
```

---

Output:

```
   id    A    B    C    D    E   F   Z              joined_column
0   0  yes   no  yes   no  yes  no  no    yes no yes no yes no no
1   1   no   no  yes   no   no  no  no      no no yes no no no no
2   2  yes  yes  yes  yes  yes  no  no  yes yes yes yes yes no no
```